# Is it possible with Antlr to detect in which rule of my grammar/part of my grammar an error happend?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I build an application where an user can create boolean rules and customizable functions based on boolean rules: 
Here an Example:

> ((A == True) || (B == True)) && ( C >= 3
>   && D == 60) && count{[E == True, F == False, G ==
>   True,] > 2}

the first part of this rule are common boolean comparisons. the second part starting with "count" is a function, where at least 2 statements have to true for the second part to be true. 
Is it possible with Antlr in which kind of my rule an error happend?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at the parse tree with grun (TestRig) or intellij plugin etc...

Comment: I want to check it in my java code. Is it there also possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question